# XmlSyntaxException vs XmlException in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception, xmlexception

Which is prefer in what case in the concept of reuse predefined exception classes?

For example I was parsing a document using XmlReader and faced with inconsistent close tag:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<element1>
    <element2>
        some content
    </element3>
</element1>
```

What to throw?

It should be noted that this two exceptions do not inherit one another so should be caught separately.

Comment: Wouldn't `XmlReader` itself throw the exception? Why are you considering throwing it yourself?

Comment: @JonSkeet, XmlReader allows low level access to XML, so I can use it for handling a document node by node and make any decision by myself.

Comment: But this is invalid XML, isn't it? Or are you adding additional requirements *on top of* normal XML?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes it's invalid XML, but XmlReader doesn't know that as operates by individual nodes, not elements. And yes I have additional requirements for such case.

Comment: It would really help if you'd give an example of such invalid XML. I'd expect `XmlReader` to pick up on it - it only gives *events* for individual nodes, but I'd expect it to have enough context to notice that (for example) you were closing a different tag to the one you opened.

Comment: (I've just validated that it *does* indeed do that.)